# MVC razor display element that can be edited by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working with a table that I would like to have display text but also have that text updated by javascript.

I can create a readonly textbox and have javascript edit that, but I would rather just have some text on the screen. Here is a sample that has a DisplayFor which displays text and a readonly textbox which shows the same text.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProjectSubmissions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber)
        </td>
        <td>                
            @Html.TextBox("recordsToSort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber", Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber, new { @id = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber", @class = "SortOrder", @readonly = "readonly" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

My javacript can edit the textbox like this:

```
$(".sortable-table tr").each(function (index, element) {
    var hiddenInput = $(element).find(".SortOrder").first();
    hiddenInput.val(index);
});
```

Can I write javascript that will update the DisplayFor? Or should I use a different element than DisplayFor that javascript can update?

UPDATE:
I'd like to end up with something like this (I would like to keep the hidden `.SortOrder` element.):

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProjectSubmissions.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="@Html.Id("recordstosort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber")" class="SortOrderDisplay">@Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber</span>
            @Html.Hidden("recordsToSort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber", Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber, new { @id = "recordsToSort[" + i + "].ChapterNumber", @class = "SortOrder" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And javascript like this:

```
$(".sortable-table tr").each(function (index, element) {
    var hiddenInput = $(element).find(".SortOrder").first();
    hiddenInput.val(index);

    var displayInput = $(element).find(".SortOrderDisplay").first();
    if (displayInput !== 'undefined') {
        displayInput.text = index;
    }
});
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: `displayFor` is just a razor helper that will generate HTML from a template before it is sent to the browser. Once the page is loaded in the browser, you can change that HTML with JavaScript, regardless of how it was generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery text instead of val.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ProjectSubmissions.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td class="SortOrder">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber)
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Then the javascript would be

```
$(".sortable-table tr").each(function (index, element) {
  var hiddenInput = $(element).find(".SortOrder").first();
  hiddenInput.text(index);
});
```

Comment: Okay, that may work, but I'm still having trouble. I updated some code in my main post, but it is not working correctly.

Comment: text is a function like val so replace "displayInput.text = index;" with "displayInput.text(index);"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be used to update any element you like. The easiest way would probably be to create a span with an id property and then use `document.getElementById.innerText` to set the text.

You can easily replace the `@Html.DisplayFor` with a `<span id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.ProjectSubmissions[i].ChapterNumber)"></span>`.

This only an example, and there are several ways to go about changing text client-side.